How can I only execute sed commands after so many pattern matches in macOS?
I have a file that contains the same pattern multiple times. I am trying to get sed to perform a series of operations only for the second occurrence of that pattern. The file looks like this:
pattern
line 1
line 2
line 3
...
pattern
line 4
line 5
line 6
...
pattern
line 7
line 8
line 9

My desired output is line 4. I currently have:
sed -n '/pattern/{n;p;q;}' file
printing line 1. How can I modify my command to obtain line 4 instead? I'm using the macOS version of sed.

Try this command:
$ sed  -n '/pattern/{n;p;}' input.txt | sed -n 2p
line 4

For fifth instance use 5p instead of 2p etc.
Hardly any need for explanation.

Is there a way to quit executing the command once the second instance of the pattern is found? That'd be useful if the input file is too large...

Yes there is a way but your file will change (so you may have to work from a copy). First use sed -i '0,/pattern/{/pattern/d;}' to remove the first line that contains pattern and then use you own command sed -n '/pattern/{n;p;q;}'

With awk, count the number of times we match pattern and use getline to read the next line once we reach the count of two. After printing the line, we may quit.
$ awk '/^pattern$/ && ++count == 2 { getline; print; exit }' file 
line 4

A similar approach in Perl:
$ perl -ne 'if (/^pattern$/ && ++$count == 2) { print scalar <> }' file
line 4

Assuming we know that the pattern occurs on the very first line, a sed solution would be to remove all lines from the first to the next line matching the pattern, and then print the first of the remaining lines (and quit):
$ sed -e '1,/^pattern$/d' -e q file 
line 4

